# Does this Expected Value not exist?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $f_{X\mid Y}\sim F_s(y)$, the first success distribution, and $f_Y=ky^2$.  I want to compute $E[X]$.
Using the fact that $E[X]=E_{y}[E_{x}[X\mid Y]]$. $E_{x}[X\mid Y]]= E[F_{s}(y)]=1/y$.  Thus, $E[X]=E_{y}[\frac{1}{y}]=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y}\cdot ky^2 \, dy= k\int_0^\infty y\,dy$. Obviously the integral does not converge.  I think I might be doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I brought your MathJax code into line with standard usage in several respects.  In particular, not that $f_{X\mid Y} \sim F_s(y)$ is standard and $f_{X\mid Y}$~$F_s(y)$ is not.  The whole thing is in MathJax. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The support of $Y$ isn't $\mathbb{R}^+$.